# set z-index to a layer control in leaflet

Tags: javascript, controls, leaflet, z-index, layer

I have a leaflet map and a fullscreen button. When I push the fullscreen button, I show a custom div which overlays the map. The problem is that my div hides the control layer menu. How could I show the menu in a way that hides my div?

My div has the minimum z-index to be shown in front of the map. Ideally I would like to give a higher z-index value to the menu.

I have created a codepen example. Switch to fullscreen to understand what I'm saying.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [39.73, -104.99],
        zoom: 10,
        layers: [grayscale, cities],
        fullscreenControl: true
    });

    var baseLayers = {
        "Grayscale": grayscale,
        "Streets": streets
    };

    var overlays = {
        "Cities": cities,
        "quite": quite,
        "long": long,
        "list": list,
        "of": of,
        "options": options,
        "at": at,
        "the": the,
        "list": list,
        "and": and,
        "some":some,
        "few": few,
        "more":more
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

http://codepen.io/corand/pen/wGyJOZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append your `overlay` div as a child of your `map` div, either directly in HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px">
  <div id="overlay" class="overlay">I want this layer to be at the back of the control layer list</div>
</div>
```

or using javascript:

```
var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
var overlayDiv = document.getElementById("overlay");
mapDiv.appendChild(overlayDiv);
```

Then, set your z-index to something lower than the huge number in your example. A number as low as 1 will actually work here, but in this case let's try 9:

```
.overlay{
    position: absolute; 
    width:200px; 
    height: 600px; 
    bottom: 50px; 
    right:10px; 
    background-color: black; 
    color: white; 
    padding: 10px; 
    z-index:9; 
}
```

Then, the overlay will display as you intended. Here is a fork of your example, appending the overlay in the script:

http://codepen.io/nathansnider/pen/KzQjVv